# window.zoomLevel in Visual Studio Code auto changes to a negative value

Tags: visual-studio-code

In my visual studio code `settings.json`, the setting `window.zoomLevel` automatically changes to a negative integer value, and it's becoming hard to see the application menus.

I have tried to comment out the line, but then the menus again become hard to see and I see that in `settings.json` automatically there appeared `"window.zoomLevel":-1`.

How can I stop this setting from automatically changing?

I'm using VS Code version 1.46.1.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when I use Italian keyboard and try to comment/uncomment lines. With Italian keyboard I get each time zoom out. With Italian keyboard Ctrl+shift+backslash does the same
as with English keyboard does Ctrl-